# Kinect v2 drivers for Ubuntu (audio)

Tags: sound, kinect

Has anybody found any drivers for Kinect v2 for Ubuntu? Specifically I need drivers for the audio (the microphones) of Kinect v2.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2

Comment: Missing features:

   audio transfer :(
but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the old driver for Kinect v1 works also for Kinect v2!
so problem solved

:)

Comment: Could you please tell me how you got it running? In my case although kinect is listed as an input device in the sound settings of ubuntu, I can't seem to hear anything when I use kinect as the audio input device.